# Text for Electorate gold badge is confusing & ambiguous

Tags: discussion, badges, voting, wording, badge-description

For observers, this particular badge creates confusion. Currently Electorate badge text shows like this:

> Vote on 600 **questions** and 25% or more of total votes are on **questions**.

Does it mean:

> Vote on 600 **posts** <strike>and</strike>/or 25% or more of total votes are on **questions**.

... or something better. To me clearly, the original text is not understandable. The "and" part appearing between a number (600) and % (25) is creating confusion.

**Update**: From the dupe, I learned that the badge is intended the way it is. However below problems are still open:

1. Is this any vote or just upvote?
2. Should it be "AND" or "OR"?

Practical example: When a user upvotes 600 Qs, then he is surely eligible for the badge. Now, A user votes up 1000th post. This is also the 600th Q. Hence 60%. Is the user eligible for the badge?

Should the text be corrected?

Suggestion:

> Vote on 600 questions, which is at least 25% of total votes

Comment: "Vote on posts in 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions."

Comment: @rene, actually it's not duplicate. The text is ambiguous, which is not helpful for users. First there is a number and then there is a %. The most confusing part is "and" appearing between these 2.

Comment: The dupe asks exactly the same question, even proposes the same *fix*. I don't see much new on the table here specially as the current answer is a repeat as well.

Answer (score 3):

No, it means *questions* as it states in the text.

So what does it mean:

- You have voted on 600 questions, but 4000 times in total (so on questions and answers). You will not receive the badge since 25% of 4000 is 1000. You need 400 more votes on questions to reach the 25% threshold, without any new vote on answers to get the badge.
- You have voted on 600 questions, and 600 times in total. 100% of your votes are on questions. You get the badge.

Comment: Shouldn't there be "OR" instead of "AND" here? Let's assume that a person votes on 1000 posts, among which 600 posts are Qs (i.e. 60%). However the 600th Q is voted exactly at 1000th vote. Is that user eligible for the batch? In other case your 2nd example, where user straight away votes for 600 Qs. Also, is this only upvote or any vote?

Comment: No. Both conditions should match to get the badge.